# FreeTextBox javascript error is preventing PostBack on my DropDownList

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, freetextbox

I have one page with 3 [FreeTextBox](http://www.freetextbox.com/) controls on it. They are set up correctly, and I was using them normally until I needed to add a DropDownList control that would PostBack to the server, but I was surprised to see that the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event would never trigger. If I was to do a Post with a button, or some other server-side control, then would the event be triggered. After much debugging I found the following Javascript error was being thrown every time I selected something different on my DropDownList control:

```
TypeError: FTB_API.MainContent_MainContent_FreeTextBox1 is undefined
```

The error seems pretty straight forward;
Firebug tells me this error comes from the following function:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit()
{
    FTB_API['MainContent_MainContent_FreeTextBox1'].StoreHtml();FTB_API['MainContent_MainContent_FreeTextBox2'].StoreHtml();FTB_API['MainContent_MainContent_FreeTextBox3'].StoreHtml();
    return true;
}
```

I've tried several things without success. When I remove the FreeTextBox controls from my page, I have successful PostBacks. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**: This is some of my markup

3 FreeTextBox set up like this:

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="FreeTextBox3" JavaScriptLocation="ExternalFile" ButtonImagesLocation="ExternalFile" ToolbarImagesLocation="ExternalFile" runat="server" EnableHtmlMode="true" />
```

My DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to the question in this thread: [Hidden FreeTextBox bug on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253490/hidden-freetextbox-bug-on-firefox) It seems for some reason that when the control is not visible or is hidden (I have tabs) it behaves this way. The answer is kind of a Hack, but it works. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Set the property AutoPostBack = true of your dropdown in markup page. This will make the post back when you change the dropdown element and OnSelectedIndexChanged get triggered.

**Example :**

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drpList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="event name" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have expected answers like this since I did not post my code, or part of it. I have the AutoPostBack property set to true. I will update my question with some more code.